# Mouting error bash on ubutun on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, mount, io

I was running md5sum on a usb hard-drive via bash on Windows, but I had to terminated the program because of some errors. I tried to remount the drive and gives no error , but I was unable to `cd` ( invalid argument), so I used `df -h` and it was returned following error:

```
df: ‘/mnt/f’: Input/output error
```

Any ideas on what causes this ? The drive works just fine when I plugged it in a ubuntu machine .
I followed the instruction from here :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/